# How to use Apache Tika to extract text from a .wps file?

Tags: java, apache-tika

I am using Tika to extract text from several types of document.
java -jar tika-app-1.10.jar -T [input file]
I realize that Tika-1.10 can detect .wps file (java -jar tika-app-1.10.jar -m [*.wps] is returning metadata) but it is unable to extract text from a .wps file(java -jar tika-app-1.10.jar -T [*.wps] file returning nothing). Is there any other way It is possible to extract text from wps file in Java? 
Any help is greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your post and detail what you have tried so far, if anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Tika 1.13, we don't have a parser for wps files. We do support the old Works 7.0 spreadsheets, but not wps.  Please open an issue on our [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/tika) if you'd like us to add support.  (I frankly have no idea how much work it would take).

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this param: (for Tika 1.2)

```
--text-main     Output plain text content (main content only)
```

For Tika 1.1:

```
--text          Output plain text content
```

See here: https://tika.apache.org/1.2/gettingstarted.html

Consider to use 1.8 or 1.9 version of apache tika.

Comment: unfortunately these are not working. I am using 1.10 and tried both of them before but no luck